# RC4 encryption using We4b Browsers

Tags: ssl, encryption, browser, https, rc4-cipher

I am working on a feature where I want to decrypt the encrypted traffic which is being sent to the server. I am aware that data get encrypted to ensure that only server is able to decipher what the message was.

But I am in a situation where I need to figure out the data which was actually being sent to the server.

If I have a setup where both the "client and server" are under my control I can run the https server on the server and make the client make a curl request(preferably with RC4 encryption) so that I can decrypt the data reaching the server using the server key (using wireshark).

How do I approach this problem if the server is not under my control? Say if the server is YouTube how do I decrypt the traffic then? Is there any browser setting I can use for the same?

Comment: Probably use fiddler.

Comment: Or use `stunnel` as client, if I remember correctly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor (is included in the brand spanking new [Firefox for Web Developers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/mozilla-introduces-the-first-browser-built-for-developers-firefox-developer-edition/))

Comment: What are "We4b Browsers"?

Comment: My bad I meant Web Browser .Thanks will check these tools